# VictoryChart not filling entire div

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

I'm trying to get a VictoryChart to fill the entire container, but it's leaving a ton of white space to the right side. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<VictoryChart domainPadding={{ x: 25 }}>
    <VictoryAxis
      tickValues={categories ? categories.x : undefined}
    />
    <VictoryAxis
      tickValues={categories ? categories.y : undefined}
      domain={yAxisDomain}
      dependentAxis
      crossAxis
    />
    <VictoryBar
      cornerRadius={{ topLeft: 5, topRight: 5 }}
      data={data}
      labels={labels}
    />
  </VictoryChart>
```

And this is what is being rendered:

[image: Chart]

```
<div class="VictoryContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; user-select: none; pointer-events: none; touch-action: none; position: relative;">
   <svg width="450" height="300" role="img" aria-labelledby="victory-container-2-title victory-container-2-desc" viewBox="0 0 450 300" style="pointer-events: all; width: 100%; height: auto;">
      ...
   </svg>
   <div style="z-index: 99; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: auto;">
      <svg width="450" height="300" viewBox="0 0 450 300" style="overflow: visible; width: 100%; height: auto;"></svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved this by setting padding on the `VictoryChart` component:

```
<VictoryChart
    domainPadding={{ x: 25 }}
    padding={{ top: 50, bottom: 50, right: 0, left: 50 }}
  >
```

Comment: Thanks, I was about to apply transformations... which made everything unnecessary complicated

Comment: thank you!! so I guess Victory has a default padding ratio and you need to set it to get full control of aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks so much, been digging around so many places except this one :D